# Can I construct a citadel next to the borders of a city state?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

The description for "Constructing a Citadel" says that "If the new culture border claims hexes owned by another Civilization, you will incur a diplomatic penalty as a result."

Does this apply to city states? Are they counted as Civilizations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Citadel to steal tiles from an adjacent city state.

Just like with civilizations, doing so will result in a diplomacy hit, though unlike full civilizations, City States are much easier to bribe back into their good graces.

You will lose **50** influence if you are not allied with the City State. If you *are* allied, you will not lose any influence at all.

Comment: Also worth noting: don't build it on your hex, because you can build it up to one hex outside your territory, even if it happens to belong to the city state. More bang for your buck.